# What's a good algorithm for estimating the arc length of an algebraic curve?

Tags: algebraic-curves, computational-mathematics, arc-length

There are many very useful computational techniques for calculating the arc length of parametric curves. See for instance [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042705006023) and references therein. What I could not find easily was a similar study for non-parametric ones. Specifically, cubic algebraic curves.

My question is: can I do better than the chord length algorithm where I estimate the arc length by summing the individual line segments connecting a sample of points on the curve?

I strongly believe there must be a better (faster converging) method, especially since for every sampled point on the curve, I can easily compute the normal vector and (not so easily) other geometrical information, such as curvature, etc.

**Edit:** The curves I'm working with have a single component in the region of interest, which is a well defined simplex. Also, for these curves I have managed to develop an adaptive sampling technique which I use to find any number of points up to any precision.

Answer (score 1):

Can you even with confidence find *any* points on an algebraic curve? Even determining the number of connected components can be a mess. Consider something like

$$
(\frac{x}{1000})^{2} + (\frac{y}{1000})^{2} + A = 0
$$

For $A > 0$, the curve is empty; for $A$ just slightly less than $0$, the curve is a large-diameter circle. This shows that the arclength is ill-behaved as a function of the coefficients .... so unless you have great numerical precision, you're likely to miscalculate it.

You might say "It's OK...I'll just work with infinite-precision rationals" but are you certain that your curve contains any rational points?

TL;DR: I suspect this is hopeless to try to do well in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already sorted out the potential issues you describe. Please see updated question.